# Why is name and number being misplaced in textfile?

Tags: php, forms, file

I'm trying to collect information. I made a simple form where a user writes his name, email, mobile number and shirt size. This is my php script.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$size = $_POST['size'];


$fh = fopen("notes.txt", "a");
foreach($_POST as $data => $value){
    fwrite($fh, $data);
    fwrite($fh, "=");
    fwrite($fh, $value);
    fwrite($fh, "\r\n");
}
fwrite($fh, "\r\n");
fclose($fh); 

echo "Information Submitted";
```

The textfile is misplacing the information.

This is what I'm getting

```
name=8008799756 (Suppose to show my name I entered in the form)
email=example@gmail.com
size=Medium
Submit=Submit (number value is not being dispaced)
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<form method="post" action="myprocessingscript.php">                                        
    <input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" class="text" id="name"/>
    <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" class="text" id="email" />
    <input name="number" placeholder="Mobile Number" type="text" class="text" id="number" />
    <input name="size" placeholder="Type your Hoodie Size (Small, Medium or Large)" type="text" class="text"  id="size"/>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
</form>
```

Please let me know what mistake I'm making on this.

Comment: What do you have the `$name`, `$email` etc variables for if you don't use them?

Comment: I Was following a tutorial. The code was accumulated by following different tutorials

Comment: What are you inserting in the name field? Is it an actual name?

Comment: @Marcel I'm filling it with "Test" but the file is showing me the number field value. So, no it's not an actual name.

Comment: if you remove the \r characters from the strings you're writing, does it produce a different outcome? Also why do you append the data? Are you not accidentally looking at older information and want to use fopen('notes.txt', 'w') instead?

Comment: @LucasMoeskops If I remove the \r characters from the string, there are new lines. I'm appending the data because I don't want the file to delete my previous data.

Comment: You must have mixed up your HTML somewhere, because the output you got simply does not match your HTML markup. See this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/SMgGpBqz. Run it on your server, without changing the values of the inputs, and you will see that everything works as expected. Make sure you're providing the proper values to the right inputs.

Comment: I have checked your same code.. Its working fine..
It is giving correct output..

Comment: @Marcel Thanks it works. Would you mind telling me what was I doing wrong before?

Comment: You must have been entering the wrong data into the wrong input fields.